# Tabulator - Can't even get off the ground with Quickstart

Tags: tabulator

Okay, so what am I doing wrong? I'm using the code below from the site under "Quickstart":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="tabulator/dist/css/tabulator.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabulator/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="example-table"></div>

<script>
//define some sample data
 var tabledata = [
        {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
        {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
        {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
        {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
        {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
 ];

//create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
        data:tabledata, //assign data to table
        layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
        columns:[ //Define Table Columns
                {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
                {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
                {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
                {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
        ],
        rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
                alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
        },
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm seeing the column headings, but -- where there should be data -- there is nothing showing up!

[image: tabulator issue]

This is my 3rd attempt with this program. I have never gotten it to work correctly. I'd use something else but the examples on the website make it appear I can do what is called for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the polyfills to get it to work on IE 11.

There is more info in the docs: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/browsers#ie

Answer (score 0):

> Copy pasted your same code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="tabulator/dist/css/tabulator.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabulator/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>-->

<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="example-table"></div>

<script>
//define some sample data
 var tabledata = [
        {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
        {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
        {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
        {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
        {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
 ];

//create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
        data:tabledata, //assign data to table
        layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
        columns:[ //Define Table Columns
                {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
                {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
                {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
                {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
        ],
        rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
                alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
        },
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, I ran the snippet and it shows me an error with the `tabulator.min.js` file. Am I supposed to fix the coding in the JS file?

Comment: @Mr_Thomas my snippet gave you an error ? I am able to see it clearly on browser

Comment: Here's the error: `Error: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}'

Comment: @Mr_Thomas what happens when you click the blue button Run code snippet on this page above ?

Comment: That's what I did, and the above error is what I got. I'm running it in IE 11 (a work requirement).

Comment: @Mr_Thomas probably there is a plugin installed that is blocking the request to fetch the java script file it has to do with your browser or work setting, nothing wrong with the code